# Slow postgres result

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

My postgres results are a bit slow, no matter what query you execute

for debugging I run the following queries

```sql
SELECT 1;
-- 1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 77 ms (execution: 52 ms, fetching: 25 ms)


SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1
-- 1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 99 ms (execution: 49 ms, fetching: 50 ms)

SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 25
-- 25 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 337 ms (execution: 276 ms, fetching: 61 ms)
```

If I use `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT 1;
-- Planning Time: 0.030 ms
-- Execution Time: 0.020 ms


EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 1
-- Planning Time: 0.215 ms
-- Execution Time: 0.056 ms


EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 25
-- Planning Time: 0.250 ms
-- Execution Time: 0.066 ms
```

The above result is from datagrip and my ping to server is under 50ms but the production nodejs is in localhost of the postgres database (0ms ping), my TTFB is more than 100ms, sometimes it's 1500ms and the problem is only postgres queries, I used [server timing api](https://web.dev/custom-metrics/?utm_source=devtools#server-timing-api) and I'm sure running queries is slow, But when I use `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`, `Planning Time` and `Execution Time` of all queries is under 1ms and each request has 1 or 2 queries at max

#### Why Execution Time in EXPLAIN ANALYSE is under 1 ms and without EXPLAIN ANALYSE its Tens of times?

Comment: Can you define "slow"? And add a diagram with the different parts? What is datagrip?

Comment: Defining slow: I TTFB with less than 30ms, currently it is 250-1500 ms
No diagram needed, all queries is slow, even `SELECT 1`, [datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) is a database client

Comment: Thank you. :-) I was imprecise when using the term "diagram". What I meant was a network-diagram. Are these all on the same host/server? Or on different ip-networks? If so routing is involved.

Comment: The difference between the 0.06ms of the plan and the 10s you see is the overhead added by the network and your SQL client. Maybe you have some large column values in the result which take time to be sent and time to be processed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my nodejs application that using sequelize is in the same machine of postgres and it use `127.0.0.1` to connect database, the server has no traffic and the I am the only person test it, My TTFB is is more than 100-1500ms and the problem is running postgres queries, I tested with very simple queries like `SELECT 1`, When I remove queries, the TTFB is 50ms and it's near to my ping to server

Comment: @kometen I updated the question, it's very strange, psql in the same machine execute my complex query in 2 ms, but node.js application in the same machine with sequelize runs the query in 286ms

Comment: Well, maybe node.js fetches the results one **row at a time**, leading to more than a few network round trips?

Comment: @wildplasser I don't think so, As far as I know by default sequelize fetches all rows once ready, I will reference the official docs here, But let assume node.js fetches the results one row at a time, Why we have latency for `SELECT 1` it's only 1 row?

Comment: @wildplasser be aware that the network is `localhost` and network `latency` is near 0

Comment: Then it's node.js or your obfuscation layer (=ORM) that adds the additional overhead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used sequelize for years and I don't have issue before, I don't know what wrong here now! let me search more

Comment: I opened an issue and hope I can find the problem https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13331

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALIZE` does not lie. A stopwatch does not lie either. All the time added is in your network, your middleware, or in your frontend. Period.

Comment: As I have no same issue these years it's very strange for me, Thanks a lot every body for responses

Comment: Also keep in mind that every network access (read/write) involves a system call(and context switch) These add up, too. BTW: Most ORMs have a parameter for specifying the number of tuples to be fetched together from an open cursor.

Comment: Is your server RAM-constrained? It may be thrashing to handle both the postgresql server and your nodejs process. (Thrashing means moving copies of working RAM to and from the ssd or hard drive in an attempt to run multiple programs that don't fit.) Try doubling the RAM on your server VM, or use `htop` and look at the RAM line.

Comment: @O.Jones it's a dev server and I have 16GB total and 8GB free  RAM

Comment: @wildplasser I remember that in previous version of sequelize we have 2 options, default options is fetching all rows as it's ready, second option uses different syntax and works with events and you could set number of tuples to be fetched, today I read whole document rapidly but unable to find and reference it here

Comment: @wildplasser @O.Jones  @a_horse_with_no_name @kometen very strange behaviour, I created a gist code and run it in the my PC and connect the nodejs app to a postgres in the docker in my PC , I simply run `SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10` it executes fast (4ms) , I run the gist in the server connected to the local postgres in same machine it takes 170ms

Comment: What if you run it **twice**? What if you use `psql` from a terminal and set the `\timing` meta-command? (BTW: ICMP is not a good measure, it can be used to get an idea of the *minimal* latency, without fragmentation etc. Also it stays limited to the kernel at the receiving side)

Comment: What if you run it twice? no diff | What if you use psql from a terminal and set the \timing meta-command? I told before it's very fast 2ms in psql